# how to navigate to another screen in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to navigate to another screen with in my album component when the user click
on a album but I keep getting this error

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"AlbumScreen"} was not handled by any navigator.
```

below is my code and my try

navigation->Album->index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import styles from './style';
import { Album, TabOneParamList } from '../../types';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
// import Navigation from '../navigation';

export type AlbumProps = {
    album: Album,

}

const AlbumComponent = (props: AlbumProps) => {

    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const onPress = () => {

        navigation.navigate('AlbumScreen');
    }



    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image source={{ uri: props.album.imageUri }} style={styles.image} />
                <Text style={styles.text}>{props.album.artistsHeadline}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
}






export default AlbumComponent;
```

here is my AlbumScreen.tsx  also this is the screen I want to user to move to once they click on the Album

```
import React from 'react';

import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const AlbumScreen = () => (
    <View>
        <Text style={{ color: 'white' }} >Hello from Album Screen</Text>
    </View>
);



export default AlbumScreen;
```

also here is my  BottomTabNavigation which I add the newly created AlbumScreen just the way the HomeScreen is added

```
import {
  Ionicons,
  Entypo,
  EvilIcons,
  MaterialCommunityIcons,
  FontAwesome5,
  FontAwesome
} from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import * as React from 'react';

import Colors from '../constants/Colors';
import useColorScheme from '../hooks/useColorScheme';
import TabOneScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import AlbumScreen from '../screens/AlbumScreen';
import TabTwoScreen from '../screens/TabTwoScreen';
import { BottomTabParamList, TabOneParamList, TabTwoParamList } from '../types';

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator<BottomTabParamList>();

export default function BottomTabNavigator() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      tabBarOptions={{ activeTintColor: Colors[colorScheme].tint }}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={TabOneNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <Entypo name="home" size={30} style={{ marginBottom: -3 }} color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="store"
        component={TabTwoNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <MaterialCommunityIcons name="store" size={30} style={{ marginBottom: -3 }} color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Library"
        component={TabTwoNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <Ionicons name="library-outline" size={30} style={{ marginBottom: -3 }} color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={TabTwoNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <FontAwesome name="user-circle" size={28} style={{ marginBottom: -3 }} color={color} />,
        }}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}



// Each tab has its own navigation stack, you can read more about this pattern here:
// https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation#a-stack-navigator-for-each-tab
const TabOneStack = createStackNavigator<TabOneParamList>();

function TabOneNavigator() {
  return (
    <TabOneStack.Navigator>
      <TabOneStack.Screen
        name="TabOneScreen"
        component={TabOneScreen}
        options={{ headerTitle: 'Home' }}
      />
       <TabOneStack.Screen
        name="AlbumScreen"
        component={AlbumScreen}
        options={{ headerTitle: 'Album' }}
      />
    </TabOneStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const TabTwoStack = createStackNavigator<TabTwoParamList>();

function TabTwoNavigator() {
  return (
    <TabTwoStack.Navigator>
      <TabTwoStack.Screen
        name="TabTwoScreen"
        component={TabTwoScreen}
        options={{ headerTitle: 'Tab Two Title' }}
      />
    </TabTwoStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Here is the picture of what I am trying to do I want upon clicking on the album on the right of this image the user is direct to another screen but I keep getting the Highlighted error [my errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YP8E.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are navigating to a Screen with name as "AlbumScreen" which does not exist. That's why you are getting this error.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import styles from './style';
import { Album, TabOneParamList } from '../../types';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
// import Navigation from '../navigation';

export type AlbumProps = {
    album: Album,
}

const AlbumComponent = (props: AlbumProps) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const onPress = () => {
        navigation.navigate('Home'); 
        // Here was the error..As you can see "AlbumScreen" does not exist in Bottom Navigator that you are returning. So Either replace "AlbumScreen" with "Home" or place another route with name "AlbumScreen" in Bottom Navigator
    }
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image source={{ uri: props.album.imageUri }} style={styles.image} />
                <Text style={styles.text}>{props.album.artistsHeadline}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
}

export default AlbumComponent;
```

Comment: but I created this scree

Comment: But I created this screen

Comment: Yes you have created  `AlbumScreen.js` but its not there in `<BottomTab.Navigator>` section check once.. So the possible route for navigations are `Home` `store` `Library` `Profile` I would recommend you to use `Stack Navigator` for your case... see [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator)